# Is there a way to place a mark in bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

What I am trying to do: I want to have a pre-compiled java byte-code file, and be able to place a "mark" in some places. Later I want to analyze this file using ASM and replace mark with some code. So, how can I implement this? Currently I am trying to do it, by inserting invocations of empty static method, but I still feeling like I am doing something wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

P.S. If more general, I want to have some precompiled class template, for example:

```
public class Main {
public static void Main(String... args){
    System.out.println("Program starts!");
    //I want to insert code here
    System.out.println("Bye!");
}}
```

Comment: note that this would utterly break any code signing mechanisms. replacing data/code like that would change the file's hash signature.

Comment: What exactly is the goal? Sounds like you could accomplish something similar (and in an easier, less fragile way) with a plugin type of framework.

Comment: I making my own simple compiler, i have some code, that will not change from program to program, and i want to have precompiled template and just add code to it.

Comment: "I am making my own simple compiler" - so use antlr.

Comment: @AmirAfghani antlr takes care of lexing & parsing. This looks like the user is trying to have a fixed prologue & epilogue for the generated code.

Comment: @lmz exactly, I'm already using antlr and now need only to generate bytecode.

Comment: so why not invoke a method onEntry and onExit using something like a MethodAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Java statement without a predefined meaning, well, maybe with the exception of the empty statement `;` which doesn’t create code that you can find in the byte code. There are annotations, but these can only be used to mark another code fragment, not to create a stand-alone statement within your code.

So you have to choose a statement to assign it the meaning of being a mark in your template code and your solution of using an invocation of a dedicated empty method is a perfect candidate for such a mark. Since it’s new meaning does not rely on the kind of statement but on the *target* method which resides in a class whose name is distinguishable from all other classes, there is no conflict between your mark and other statements.

But you should consider that the framing class code is rather trivial compared to the code you will generate when implementing a compiler for any non trivial language. In most cases, the logic of patching the generated code into an existing code will exceed the complexity of just generating a complete class file.

If you really have large pieces of unchanging code you should consider placing them into their own classes and generate classes using or extending them. This simplifies the code generation and avoids code duplication (the same reason why these techniques are used in manually written code).

Comment: Note that the question talks about generating bytecode in which case you might consider `nop` a statement with no meaning. But the later point is still valid.

Comment: @Antimony: I understood the question as having the template formulated using ordinary Java source code and thus needing a Java source code construct for creating a mark which the byte code level merger recognizes. And there isn’t any source code artifact creating a `nop` instruction (at least not for granted).